# peformance metrics for monitoring IIS

Tags: iis, monitoring, zabbix, performance-monitor

I am looking forward to come up with an exhaustive list of perfomance/resource parameters that can be monitored to keep check on health of IIS Server.can you guys please help me with suggestions on what can be some baseline metrics.

Comment: Just for inspiration http://monitoringartist.github.io/zabbix-searcher/#IIS

Comment: You might also wish to search for IIS on https://share.zabbix.com/ .